# second order linear differential equation and fundamental theorem of calculus part II

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

we are given a $2$nd order d.e.

$$y'+4y+5 \int_{0}^x y dx = e^{-x}$$ when $y(0)=0$.

if we take the derivative of both sides we get :

$y''+4y'+5y=-e^{-x} $

we take the reduced equation:

$y''+4y'+5y=0$

and get an auxiliary equation

$D^2+4D+5=0$

from here we can easily get our general solution.

$Y_g(x)= C_1 e^{-2x} \cos (x)+ C_2 e^{-2x} \sin (x)$

we can also solve for a particular solution and it ends up being

$Y_p(x)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-x}$

now we are asked for a unique solution. However, we only have $y(0)=0$, $1 $ initial condition. How would we solve for the second initial condition ?

plug zero into :

$y''(x)+4y'(x)+5 y(x)=-e^{-x}$ ?

Comment: You get a one parameter family of solutions when you enforce the given initial condition. Try plugging that back into the original integro-differential equation and see what you get.

Comment: $y'(0)=1$ is what you should get

Comment: I am not exactly sure how it is you have gotten y'(0)=1

Comment: Just evaluate your original (integral) equation at $x=0$.